# Replace variable of Wordpress shortcode based on select box?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

Is it possible to do this without Ajax, solely with vanilla JS and PHP?

What I am trying to do is:

- Return the shortcode in PHP *(easy)*
- Show it on the page *(easy)*
- Allow users to select a text on the front-end *(HTML is easy, but how do I send this as a variable?)*
- Change the shortcode variable with the chosen text on the front-end and load it dynamically on the page.

My question is: what options do I have? Is it solely Ajax or can I do this with PHP and JS-only?

```
function place_function() {
   
     return '[myshortcode place="new york"]';
}
```

Comment: `Change the shortcode variable with the chosen text on the front-end and load it dynamically on the page.` -  this makes it impossible to go without AJAX

Comment: What about this? Create a shortcode, add parameter to URL and fetch that? Would that work?

Comment: Yes, you can create a dynamic link to a page that contains parameters in the URL, or you can create a form that POSTs to the server, or you could dynamically update an iframe. AJAX really seems the easiest, however, and it is a first-class citizen in JS.